# Increase the number of runnable threads in a Spring application

Tags: java, spring, multithreading, spring-boot, rabbitmq

I have a Spring application that is basically listening to some queue in RabbitMQ and consumes messages and stores them in database.

The publish rate of the queue is 200 messages per second and I need to have multiple consumers listening to it and storing them concurrently.

I have defined my listener in code like this:

```
@Service
@RabbitListener(
        bindings = @QueueBinding(
                exchange = @Exchange(value = "my-exchange", type = "topic"),
                value = @Queue("my-queue"),
                key = "my-key"),
        concurrency = "13"

)
@Slf4j

public class MyService {
    @RabbitHandler
    public void handle(byte[] data, Channel channel, @Header(AmqpHeaders.DELIVERY_TAG) long deliveryTAG) throws IOException {
        // my code        
    }
}
```

I have also defined this configs in YAML file:

```
spring:
  task:
    execution:
      pool:
        core-size: 40
        max-size: 60
        queue-capacity: 1000
  rabbitmq:
    addresses: ${AMQ_HOST}
    username: ${SECRETS_AMQUSER}
    password: ${SECRETS_AMQPASS}
    virtual-host: my-vhost
    listener:
      simple:
        prefetch: 100
```

But when I run the program in Kubernetes and get the threads status from Prometheus, I get this graph:
[threads status graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qlfue.png)

The red line is runnable threads, purple is timed-waiting and the yellow one is waiting.
As it is clear in the graph, the number of my runnable threads (the red line) are no more than 8, which is not what I need.

I would be really thankful if you could assist me with increasing the number of my runnable threads.

I have tried this java environments: `-XX:ThreadStackSize=256 -XX:ParallelGCThreads=16`.

But they didn't work and still I got no more than 8 threads.

Comment: Setting `ThreadStackSize` lower than its default (256 KiB instead of a default of 1MiB) is unlikely to help anything (and makes it more likely for your application to break with a StackOverflowError), and using `ParallelGCThreads=16` has zero effect on **your** threads, it only informs the number of threads the garbage collector uses. Why do you think there is a problem. Maybe all those threads are doing nothing, because there is nothing for them to do, so they are waiting...

Comment: @MarkRotteveel Those were chatGPT's suggestion about this problem. I have run the application both with and without them and in both scenarios it didn't work. And about the other thing you said, well I think there must be something for the threads. I once set the pre-fetch count of my consumers on 5,  which then in that case I thought that more threads would be run since consumers would be filled sooner, however it also didn't change anything. But I don't know for sure, maybe you're right and there's nothing for the threads to do.

Comment: ChatGPT is entirely useless for things like this, because it is basically a very convincing bullshit generator. You cannot trust anything it says, and it is more than likely to give you a wrong, or, at minimum, an incomplete answer. It is not a replacement for reading documentation and tutorials.